# How can I update a specific cell in a sqlite database through python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database full of numbers but as a string. My main goal is to get a cell in the SQLite database, turn it into a float and then update the cell with it. However I don't understand how to update a specific cell in a SQLite database. Here is my code.

```
for row in cur:
    for col in row:
        try:
            fcol = float(col)
            cur.execute('UPDATE test SET ')
        except:
            print("FAIL")
            print(col)
            continue
        print("Replaced",col)
    print("Row done")
print("Completed")
```

Basically my question is how I can update a specific cell of a SQLite database.

Comment: What is the type of the `col` column, as declared in your `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: The whole dataset is just full of numbers however they are in strings

Comment: It's very long but here's a sample. It just keeps going on like that.
CREATE TABLE "test" (
 "row" INTEGER,
 "1" TEXT,
 "2" TEXT,
 "3" TEXT,
 "4" TEXT,
 "5" TEXT,
 "6" TEXT,
 "7" TEXT,
 "8" TEXT,
 "9" TEXT,
 "10" TEXT,
 "11" TEXT,
 "12" TEXT,
 "13" TEXT,
 "14" TEXT,
 "15" TEXT,
 "16" TEXT,
 "17" TEXT,
 "18" TEXT,
 "19" TEXT,
 "20" TEXT,
 "21" TEXT,
 "22" TEXT,
};

Comment: What is a "cell"?  Databases have tables.  Tables have columns.  Are you asking how to update a specific column in a specific row?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the column(s) is defined as `TEXT`, so the values are always going to be strings when fetched.  There are a few ways to handle this.

First of all, you can cast them to `float` or `Decimal` after retrieving them from the database.  This is inconvenient and error-prone.

A better approach might be to create a new column, with type `REAL`, and load it with the data from the old column.  This example creates and populates a table and then demonstrates adding a new column.

```py
import random
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test')
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER, col TEXT)')
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test (id, col) VALUES (?, ?)',
                    [(i, random.random(),) for i in range(3)])
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute('SELECT col FROM test')
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
    print()
    cur.execute('ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN new_col REAL')
    cur.execute('UPDATE test SET new_col = CAST(col AS REAL)')
    conn.commit()
    try:
        # Not all versions of Sqlite support DROP COLUMN
        cur.execute('ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN col')
        conn.commit()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        conn.rollback()
    cur.execute('SELECT id, new_col FROM test')
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Thirdly, you could create a new table with the correct datatypes and copy the data from the original table. As before, this example creates and populates a table and then demonstrates copying to a new table.

```
with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test')
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER, col TEXT)')
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test (id, col) VALUES (?, ?)', 
                    [(i, random.random(),) for i in range(3)])
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute('SELECT col FROM test')
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
    print()
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2')
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test2 (id INTEGER, col REAL)')
    # The order of SELECTed columns must match the target columns.
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test2 (id, col)
                   SELECT t1.id, CAST(t1.col AS REAL) 
                   FROM test t1 
                   WHERE true""")
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute('SELECT id, col FROM test2')
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Once you are happy with the result you can drop the original table, and even rename the new table if you want.

In the examples I drop and recreate the original table each time - you don't want to do this with your table!  The examples use a simple two-column table but the logic can be extended to handle multiple columns.

Comment: I've looked at your coded solutions and I've tried them out. However, my database is extremely big. And it's really big to the point that I can't find a way to make a new table for the final result. This is why I took your first where I'm just taking every cell in the table and then converting it to a float. So far the only thing I need to do is to update every cell to the floated version. And that's the thing that I don't know how to do as all articles online only talk about how to update a row or column but not a specific cell.

Comment: You could update a single cell with `UPDATE tbl SET col = ? WHERE id = ?` - the `WHERE` clause lets you specify which cell(s) is updated.  But you can't change the underlying _type_ of the data in the cell - if the column type is `TEXT` then the values it contains will be text.